# How to transfer data from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to merge one column with another one but not sure what should I use insert or update statement.

> The table looks like this

```
marketId |    Product      | Phone | Value |
1          washing machine    null    800
1          air condition      null    300
1          refrigerator       null    600
1          TV                 null    500
2          washing machine    null    850
2          air condition      null    300
2          refrigerator       null    600
2          TV                 null    500
```

> I want to get result like this -

```
marketId |    Product      |  Value |
1          washing machine    800
1          air condition      300
1          refrigerator       600
1          TV                 500
1          Phone              null
2          washing machine    850
2          air condition      200
2          refrigerator       550
2          TV                 500
2          Phone              null
```

Tried few things (update/insert statements), but I was unsuccessful. Do you have some other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Is phone always  null?

Comment: What is the logic behind to get the sample result you posted?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
select market_id, product, value
from t
union all
select market_id, 'phone', null
from t;
```